# Is there a way to access previously created divs?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating divs with dynamic names using php such as:

```
echo "<div class=\"".$row['country']."\">"
```

So it's going to first create a series of divs such as ...

```
<div class="America">
   //stuff goes in here
</div>

<div class="Germany">
   //stuff goes in here
</div>

<div class="Singapore">
   //stuff goes in here
</div>
```

But later on in the code after the "Germany" div has already been created, I'm going to make another mysql query to a different table and I want to access the "Germany" class and add content in it. It then becomes something like...

```
 <div class="Germany">
    <p> Germany has x number of people </p>
    <p> The most popular car in Germany is x </p>
</div>
```

I know with Jquery there is the append() function. Is there something similar in PHP where I can access a div that's already been created and add stuff to it?

Note: all of this is in one php file that loads all the content when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create an array like

```
$div["Amereica"] = "America"
```

And in future you can append value to this array. eg.

```
$div["Amereica"] .= 'text to append';
```

And finally you can use implode function or using other array functions you can crate final html.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done. You can use output buffering to capture all output. Then you can use an HTML DOM parser to modify that output. After that, you can flush the lot.

But this will work only once and it will seriously slow down your script. Don't do it, it smells of bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to create multiple variables like

```
$css['America'];
$css['Germany'];
$general_output;
```

etc and, while you are building your site, just add info to the required variable.

Once you get to the end of the page, print them in the right order and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to re-access that element, you're probably looking for [DOM functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

Comment: DOM parsing would not allow him to change the content he has already output.

Comment: @Asad you're right, of course... I forgot to mention that in my answer, only wanted to point out the asker to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no.

You can't change HTML code produced by PHP, because that code is already sent to browser, and PHP works on server side.

One of complicated answers is @GolezTrol answer.